# Not all elements are being loaded on all of time - mostly on older browsers

Tags: html, dom

So I'm working on a site; http://taste.fourseasons.com/ and I noticed that when viewing the website the from old browsers, parts of the page are not showing up. This happens about 40% of time. Sometimes headlines will be missing, sometimes whole blocks of text.

Anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost certainly has to do with the fact that new ("HTML5") tags are being used.  These are not supported by IE8-, and it will not render them properly or apply styles to them.  I've created a very simple script that will at least let styles be applied to them:

https://github.com/ajcrites/ie.html5.html

The point is that `document.createElement('nav')` will allow `<nav>` to be used and styles to be applied to it.  This of course has to be done before `<nav>` elements are loaded in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks @Explosions Pills, It is written in HTML5. I assume your script  is similar to the HTML5 'shiv' I've read about?

Comment: @user15624 yes it is very similar and probably inferior, but I think simpler

Comment: seems I can't upvote as I don't have enough rep points. I did mark this post as helpful, is that how I accept the answer? Trying your script out now, thanks again!

Comment: after doing some research I figured out how to accept the answer - for anyone else new to this site it's by clicking the check mark next to the arrow. I went back and did this to all my questions that have been answered and gained enough rep points to vote your answer up.